# Layout of website not correct in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

The Stack Overflow community has been of great help to me in completing my website. Just when all the basic functionality was achieved on my website, this problem surfaced. The layout of my website was absolutely perfect across browsers till this noon. But after that, the layout is not as desired on MOZ Firefox. The website is located at http://tinyurl.com/poobb3m

Can anyone help in locating the problem?

**Update**
The layout is fine when (www) is added before the domain. But it is messed up when the naked URL is served. Try this link: http://tinyurl.com/q3uwbf3

This is what it is when www is not included in the URL:
[image: Without www]

This is what it should actually be (and what it is when www is included in the URL:
[image: with www]

Comment: Can you remember what you changed between now and then?

Comment: which Fire-Fox browser version you used?

Comment: And since I can't see any difference, can you post a pic of what it is and what it's supposed to be?

Comment: Nothing changed since now I then.. It seems I just accidentally opened the naked url (without www) and noticed the difference. Have you tried both the links above in FF? There is a difference in both of them.

Comment: I have included the screenshots in the question. Do take a look.
@IshanJain Firefox version is irrelevant. I tried this on my Android's Firefox and the result was same. Probably the problem is not with just Firefox. I would update after checking in other browsers as well.

Comment: Both URLs look exactly the same when I open them in FFv23.  Do you see any console errors or warnings?  The only difference I can spot in your screenshot is the ad is being overflowed.  Maybe try a DNS flush and reload (wild guess).

Comment: I'd recommend you actually find out why it's overflowing in one and not the other, but you could band-aid the problem by setting the ad's parent to `overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: But why should the domain cause a problem anyway???

Comment: It shouldn't, I was thinking the one URL was cached and the other wasn't and was maybe not loading some CSS; ignore that.  I can't reproduce your problem, so the only solution I can offer is the CSS above.

Comment: I tried it.. but it didn't solved the problem..

Comment: Cached CSS could still be the problem (i.e. the browser has cached the www'd CSS but not the other one, so it loaded the most recent version of the other one). Clear your cache and try again. By the way, in the screenshots, the font on the www one is smaller. Are you sure you're not zoomed in or anything?

Comment: No.. I am not zoomed in, and I do not think cached CSS is a problem because I have cleared my cache several times and am still experiencing this problem. I just tried this on Chrome, but the problem was not there. So probably this is a problem only in FF because I can reproduce the prob;em on my Android's FF too.

Comment: I can tell you what the problem is, but not why:  The ad is being displayed larger in your first case, so it's being overflowed.  It would be really helpful if you provided your version number, because again, I tested with Firefox and don't see the issue.  Also, tell any warnings or errors you get in the console.  (Tools -> Web Developer -> Web Console -> [Reload the page].  Also, the CSS I referenced above:  You have it applied to the AD, not the parent.  Put it in `.header`